# C# - Password Hash in webservices

Tags: c#, hash, passwords, entity

So I need to, via webservice authenticate an user with a given username and password. I have a SQL Server Database generated using CodeFirst Entity Framework. My problem is that the password isn't directly stored into the database as it is hashed with salt which I am not aware of. So, how should I deal with this issue? It's pretty pointless to try to obtain the correct hash since I don't know the salt they used.

Any suggestions on how I should tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the Salt you cannot validate the password.

You need to be able to retrieve the Salt and Hash from the DB for the User, every user should have a different salt.  Then apply the Salt to the incoming Password, compute the Hash, and compare it with the stored hash.